# Using PHP sessions after login

Tags: php, database, session

Ok so I am new to PHP. I have encountered a problem while using sessions. I have created a small booking system where a user can register, login and book events. Basic stuff apart from the sessions. The problem I have is once a user registers and then logs in, if they want to change their username from there page they can. But if a user does change their username they cannot log back into the system. HELP PLEASE.

login.php page

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("flexiflash", $con);

$username = strtolower($_POST['user']);
$password = strtolower($_POST['pass']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Username = '$username' AND Password = '$password'");
$usertype = mysql_query("SELECT Usertype FROM user");

if(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)))
{
    $usertype = $row['Usertype'];
    //if an admin user, redirect to admin.html

    if ($usertype == 'Admin')
    {
        //Creating the session
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = 'admin';
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['User_ID'];

        header('Location: admin.php');
    }

    if ($usertype == 'User')
    {
        $_SESSION['usertype'] = 'user';
        // more??

        header('Location: user.php');
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<h2>Why do I see this page?</h2>";
    echo "<p>Your username may have not been found</p>";
    echo "<p>Your password was entered incorrectly</p>";
    echo "<h2>What can I do?</h2>";
    echo "<p>double check you have entered your username and password correctly</p>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<a href='index.html' alt='click to go back home'>Click here to go back to login page!</a>";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

update_user.php page

```
<?php
session_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("flexiflash", $con);

$username = $_POST['U_user1'];
$username_confirm = $_POST['U_user2'];
$id = $_SESSION['userid'];

if ($username == $username_confirm)
{
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Username = ' " . $username . " ' WHERE Username = '$id'");
    echo "Record Updated Succesfully";
}
else 
{
    echo "<h2>Why do I see this page?</h2>";
    echo "<p>Your username may have not been found</p>";
    echo "<h2>What can I do?</h2>";
    echo "<p>double check you have entered your username correctly</p>";
}

mysql_close($con);
```

?>

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: You are using unfiltered POST data directly in your query. No way that could go wrong...

Comment: Where is the registration bit?

Comment: I think you have  username  instead user id in where : mysql_query("UPDATE user SET Username = ' " . $username . " ' WHERE Username = '$id'");

Comment: Why would you "strtolower" the entered password?

Comment: They are logging in with the username and password. Then they are given the option to change the username. Is the value getting stored in the database? If so, ideally you should log them out and then they should use the new username to log in. But I think it's wrong to give them an option to change the username itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your update query you are sticking spaces around the username:

```
"UPDATE user SET Username = ' " . $username . " '...
```

So a username "foo" becomes " foo ".

Also this part I think is wrong:

```
WHERE Username = '$id'
```

It looks like it should be:

```
WHERE User_ID = '$id'
```

**Warning**: you have some *serious* security issues with your code, right now you are wide open to SQL injection attacks. Read up on properly filtering user input.

Also, you are using deprecated `mysql_*` methods, and should switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Then use prepared statements with bound parameters!

Comment: Thanks for all the help folks. Like I say i'm new to PHP.

Comment: Im using this old version just to learn the basics for now. plus there will be no security issues at the moment because it is not live. Its all done locally. I am creating this to learn. Next stop, a small social media site :)

Answer (score 0):

You UPDATE statement needs to be:

```
"UPDATE user SET Username = '$username' WHERE User_id = '$id'"
```

You don't need the extra quotation marks around '$username'; starting the string with double-quotation marks means the string will recognize variables as such.  But the most important part is that you need to identify the user by ID, not username.  If you allow end users to update their username, you need to use a different variable as a unique identifier.  This way you always know which record in the Database belongs to them, even if their username changes.

One more note - it doesn't look like you're setting a $_SESSION variable for user_id if the user is not an admin.  You will need to do this as well.

Comment: How would I create this session variable then?

Comment: Same way you do for Admins - "$_SESSION['userid'] = $row['User_ID'];".  It just didn't look like you had that in your "if" block for users who weren't Admins.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the username , update the session also with this new username then It will work  fine.

Comment: he's not storing the username in session